# Database Schema for Registered Customers and Guest Checkout

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, e-commerce

For an ecommerce site that allows both Guest checkouts and registered user checkouts, how will you handle the 2 different customer groups?

1. Do you store both groups in the same table `customers` which has a foreign key `customer_group_id` pointing to another table `customer_groups`? In this case, will you worry about duplicate guest checkouts "polluting" the `customers` table?
2. How will the information captured for the 2 customer groups be different? I am thinking the difference is that the guest checkout customers will not have a password thats it.

Answer (score 10):

I store customer information directly in the order rather than rely on the information in the customer record.  That does a couple things:

1. I don't have to have a guest user in the customer database
2. If my customer information changes, or if a customer wants to ship one item to one place, and another item to another place the information about the order will still be correct.

I view order information as historical data.  It should not change because something else in your database changes.  For example if I order something from you, and at some later time I move and update my billing and shipping information, you should still know that the previous order was billed and shipped to the previous address.  If you rely on the relationship between the customer and the order to retain bill to and ship to information, Once I move and update my profile, you think you shipped to my new address.  You may not see that as an issue, but it will be.

You can still get the current information from the customer record to populate the fields on the order if the customer has an account.  For a guest, he has to type it every time.

Answer (score 0):

The common entity is a Checkout. The guest checkout would be a null FK link on the checkout entity to a registerd user entity.

Comment: Will you store the shipping/billing information in the `checkouts` table? If so, does that mean you have to store the shipping/billing info on both `users` and `checkouts` table.

Comment: An order has a shipping and billing address. A customer can have a shipping and billing address. There only needs to be one unique address and then two linking tables. Like when ordering on ecommerce sites, the option to "set as my default address" under the shipping or billing option tells the database to use the same address on the customer side that it will use on the order side.